# Hybrid USB Charging (Power Delivery) and PC Connection

Tags: power-supply, power, usb-c

I have an Oculus Quest 2 that I am using with my PC for running VR games from Steam. The headset needs to be plugged in while playing Steam VR games. My desktop does not have a USB-C native plug, but does have USB 3 ports that I am using.

The device slowly dies because it uses more power than it draws, so I'm trying to find some kind of hybrid adapter which can provide power delivery >= 2 amps while being a more or less transparent pass-through to the PC for data transfer.

I'm having a hard time even searching for something like this. Does anyone know if such an adapter exists?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of something hard to find how about
http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=254643475962&category=90718&pm=1&ds=0&t=1604346693155

Note the separate power supply connector on the back.[image]